# Run manage.py syncdb error with Django 1.5

Tags: django

When I upgrade django from 1.4 to 1.5, and run manage.py syncdb, there is a error as following

> $ python manage.py syncdb
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/**init**.py:219: DeprecationWarning: You have no filters defined on the 'mail_admins' logging handler: adding implicit debug-false-only filter. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#request-exceptions-are-now-always-logged
>     DeprecationWarning)
>
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify_exists'

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 3):

The `verify_exists` keyword argument for a [model `URLField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) has been removed (depreciated since 1.3.1). You can read more in the [django depreciation notes for 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#id2):

> django.db.models.fields.URLField.verify_exists will be removed. The feature was deprecated in 1.3.1 due to intractable security and performance issues and will follow a slightly accelerated deprecation timeframe.

The simple fix is to find the offending `models.URLField` in the appropriate `models.py` that is throwing the error and remove the `verify_exists=True`, i.e:

```
# Before
some_site = models.URLField(verify_exists=True)

# After
some_site = models.URLField()
```